# Find count of highest occurences mapped from a different sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two source sheets, one which has several columns with several entries (three columns with thousands of rows to be exact, source location, destination location and type/service":
Example entries of a cell: "anton paper cupboard data entry" (separation is actually by newline, not space)

The second source sheet is manually crafted and contains a mapping of locations and services (hundreds) to a value of "small, medium, large, x-large"
I can have the layout of this however works best but right now i have one column of "location" and another with "service" with "small,medium,large,x-large" written right next to it.

Now what I need to achieve is on a result sheet, I will have six columns with the same amount of rows as the first source sheet: SRCLOC-Name,SRCLOC-#,DSTLOC-Name,DSTLOC-#,SRV-Name,SRV-#
In each column I need to count the "largest" occurence.

Meaning if ten "objects" in a cell were mapped to medium, five to large and two were mapped to x-large, I would need to somehow indicate "2x x-large" (e.g. SRCLOC-Name would change to x-large and SRCLOC-# would indicate the number of occurences that were mapped to x-large)

I tried to solve this with VLOOKUP etc. but got stuck on how to match various strings in a cell (which I dont even know how to separate and test against) against a map of variables.

Example with pictures:

[SrcData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx4iV.png)

[Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LKki.png)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihwbR.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: should I add an example work sheet? not sure how I could attach a file here

Comment: I added an example with pictures, the results picture is obviously static right now and something I would like to automate with formulas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is typically a task for Power Query and Language M (included in Excel since 2016).

You first have to declare table (Insert/Table) for all the table you use, and name them SrcData, LocationMapping, ServiceMapping. Add a new table Size with the columns Size (small/medium/large/x-large), and N (1/2/3/4).

Tables are presented with half the lines coloured.

Then go in each LocationMapping, ServiceMapping and Size, and in Data, "From a table or a range", dropdown the menu "close and load", "close and load in...", then select the "no connection" menu and press OK. You will have on the right side the different connections which will make the link between Power Query and the tables.

Now, go in the main table (SrcData). "From a table or a range", then "advanced editor", and replace the program by

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="SrcData"]}[Content],
    #"Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SRCLOC", type text}, {"DSTLOC", type text}, {"Service", type text}}),
    Src1 = Table.AddColumn(#"Type",
          "SRCLOC-N",each let sp = Text.Split([SRCLOC],"#(lf)"), 
                        l = List.Transform(sp,each  Size{[ Size= LocationMapping{[Location=_]}[Size]  ]}[N]  ),
                        max = List.Max(l),
                        filter = List.Select(l, each _ = max)
                      in
                        Size{[N=max]}[Size]),
    Src2 = Table.AddColumn(Src1,
          "SRCLOC#",each let sp = Text.Split([SRCLOC],"#(lf)"), 
                        l = List.Transform(sp,each  Size{[ Size= LocationMapping{[Location=_]}[Size]  ]}[N]  ),
                        max = List.Max(l),
                        filter = List.Select(l, each _ = max)
                      in
                        List.Count(filter)),
    Dst1 = Table.AddColumn(Src2,
          "DSTLOC-N",each let sp = Text.Split([DSTLOC],"#(lf)"), 
                        l = List.Transform(sp,each  Size{[ Size= LocationMapping{[Location=_]}[Size]  ]}[N]  ),
                        max = List.Max(l),
                        filter = List.Select(l, each _ = max)
                      in
                        Size{[N=max]}[Size]),
    Dst2 = Table.AddColumn(Dst1,
          "DSTLOC#",each let sp = Text.Split([DSTLOC],"#(lf)"), 
                        l = List.Transform(sp,each  Size{[ Size= LocationMapping{[Location=_]}[Size]  ]}[N]  ),
                        max = List.Max(l),
                        filter = List.Select(l, each _ = max)
                      in
                        List.Count(filter)),
    Svc1 = Table.AddColumn(Dst2,
          "Service-N",each let sp = Text.Split([Service],"#(lf)"), 
                        l = List.Transform(sp,each  Size{[ Size= ServiceMapping{[Service=_]}[Size]  ]}[N]  ),
                        max = List.Max(l),
                        filter = List.Select(l, each _ = max)
                      in
                        Size{[N=max]}[Size]),
    Svc2 = Table.AddColumn(Svc1,
          "Service#",each let sp = Text.Split([Service],"#(lf)"), 
                        l = List.Transform(sp,each  Size{[ Size= ServiceMapping{[Service=_]}[Size]  ]}[N]  ),
                        max = List.Max(l),
                        filter = List.Select(l, each _ = max)
                      in
                        List.Count(filter)),
    SelectColumns = Table.SelectColumns(Svc2,{"SRCLOC-N", "SRCLOC#", "DSTLOC-N", "DSTLOC#", "Service-N", "Service#"})
in
    SelectColumns
```

OK will previsualise the result. Close and load will create a sheet with the result.

Note, the program will be picky with the table names and their columns, including the character cases.

(The program could have been optimized... some computations are done twice... but if it is OK, I will left it like this).

Comment: sounds a bit complicated, do you happen to have an example file with that?
I will try this on monday and mark it as answer if I can manage to make that work somehow

Comment: See http://www.sinerj.org/~loyer/PowerUser_sheet.xlsx Note: if you change the data, you will have to go to the Result table and right-click/actualize.